# Problems with running Python 32 in Sublime Text 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, ide, runtime, sublimetext2

I know that there are lots of questions about running Python in Sublime Text 2, but i have a problem.

I've changed "Python.sublime-build" file in AppData package on this one

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\Program Files\\Python32\\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Where "C:\Program Files\Python32\python.exe" is my own path. When I press Ctrl + B. I see "building..." and than the inscription disapeers and nothing happens.

What to do. help me please!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be modifying any files in `AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 2/Packages/` unless they're in the `User/` directory. Any changes will be overwritten upon upgrade, and if you break something (unless you've made backups) you might not be able to fix it without reinstalling.

So, change `Packages/Python/Python.sublime-build` back to the following:

```json
{
    "cmd": ["python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Next, create a new file `Packages/User/Python3.sublime-build` with the following contents:

```json
{
    "cmd": ["c:/Program Files/Python32/python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Save the file, then go to the `Tools -> Build System` menu and select `Python3`. You should now be able to run a Python 3 file by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>. I'd suggest running the one below, as it will show if your Python installation is working properly:

```py
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

Comment: The same result, nothing happens.

Comment: @Luchnik - are you sure that `c:\Program Files\Python32` is the location of `python.exe`, and it has been installed properly? Also, what is the program you're trying to run? Try running the one at the bottom of my answer (make sure you save the file first). Also, try running it from the command line to ensure Python is working correctly.